# Rotate videoview while livestreaming

Tags: android, android-videoview, live-streaming

I have a videoview which play live streaming links fine in potrait mode with some channels listing below the videoview.
My problem is that i want to rotate my videoview to landscape mode (fullscreen and without showing the channel lists in the bottom) without buffering again or loading the stream again.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add `android:configChanges="orientation"` to Activity tag on AndroidManifest.xml
it will stop the calling of onCreate() while rotation and prevent your video from rebuffering.

and  use the following code in your activity.

```
//this is called when the screen rotates.
// (onCreate is no longer called when screen rotates due to manifest, see: android:configChanges)
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
{
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    int orientation = newConfig.orientation;
    if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
    {
      Log.d("tag", "Portrait");//Do your layout changes here
    }        
    else if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
    {
       Log.d("tag", "Landscape");//Do your layout changes here
    }
}
```

Mark as up if it works for you.

Comment: i have tried it but it shows the "channel lists" at bottom of the player, i want my videoview goes fullscreen

Comment: You can set the visibility of your channel list to <b>View.GONE</b> or <b>View.VISIBLE</b> as you desire on rotation change.

Comment: this is the way, the only thing you have to do is manage your layouts on rotation as per your requirement.

Comment: i have tried this approach also, didnt workout for me as videoview doesnt go to "fullscreen".

Comment: Try my another answer.